# QFiledialog returns the incorrect directory

Tags: c++, qt, dng

A snippet of what i'm using looks like this

```
QDir lastDir;
QFileDialog dial(this);

dial.getOpenFileName(this,
                     tr("Open File"),
                     QString("/home"),
                     tr("Raw Images (*.nef *.NEF *.dng *.DNG)"));

lastDir = dial.directory();
qDebug() << lastDir;
```

The output, is completely wrong, no matter which directory I end up in. However, the incorrect directory is always the same.

AFAICT i'm doing nothing wrong here. What is going on here? Cheers

Comment: Hmm, should have read the docs closer. "Returns the directory currently being displayed in the dialog." Strange that it returns a directory I never looked at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getOpenFileName()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) is a static function which immediately opens a "file picker" dialog and returns, once the user is finished with the dialog, "an existing file selected by the user". You use it like this (note the use of `::` and the class name `QFileDialog` instead of the object name):

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                 tr("Open File"),
                 QString("/home"),
                 tr("Raw Images (*.nef *.NEF *.dng *.DNG)"));
```

[`directory()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfiledialog.html#directory) is non-static and returns "the directory currently being displayed in the dialog". This function is meant to be called while the dialog is still open, it's intended for use cases which are not covered by the static calls.

---

What is happening here is you have instantiated an object, called a static function on it (which won't affect its state), and then called `directory()` which will just reflect the original state of the object, which is probably the working directory. Instead, you need to store the return value of the `getOpenFileName()` call in a variable, as shown above.

If you want to ask the user to just choose a directory, you could consider using [`getExistingDirectory()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) instead. Alternatively, if you want to extract the directory from the filename, the [`QDir`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdir.html) class has some functions useful for this.

Comment: Thanks, after reading the docs a bit more I realised my error. What I was after was a qdir/qstring of the dialogs viewed directory. In the end I just used the returned QString from _getOpenFileName_ and cut out the filename. That way the next time I open the filedialog i'm back at the last folder I viewed. What was weird was that the directory from _directory_ was "/media/data/Projects/python/Gereqi/icons" when in fact my working dir was "/media/data/Projects/c++/rawviewer/". Weird.